# Reload jquery plugin on Resize

Tags: jquery, resize, bxslider

I would like the [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) to restart so it can recalculate the `div` dimensions and fit the new width and height when the window is resized.

I was wondering, how in jQuery you can reload a plugin on resize.

I would like that simple function

```
//Home slider function
function hSlider(){
    $('.hCarousel').bxSlider({
        displaySlideQty: 3
    });
}

$(window).resize(function(e){
    hSlider();
}).resize();
```

to be reloaded on `resize()`

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried putting it inside `resize()`?  Where is your code attempt?

Comment: Updated my code, I made a function with the plugin in it and call it in the resize() but the thing is that it append a new plugin instead of reloading it.

Comment: This depends on the plugin, the plugin should be responsive to give you a desired result.

Comment: Does the plugin have a `remove` or `destroy` method?  If so, you'd use it to remove the original one before recreating it.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of [this page](http://bxslider.com/options).  See `destroyShow()`.

Comment: Yeah it destroy but doesn't reload. Even with reloadShow();

Comment: It can not "reload" it if you "destroy" it.  Destroy it and recreate it instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the api on http://bxslider.com/options you should be able to call either of these functions.

> destroyShow() Destroys the active slideshow 
>   
> reloadShow() Reinitialize
>   a slide show

```
//Home slider function
$('.hCarousel').bxSlider({
    displaySlideQty: 3
});


$(window).resize(function(e){
   $('.hCarousel').reloadShow();
});
```

*note untested but read the api*

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the problem not in resize function, you asking about reinit bxSlider? Look at this answer: [resetting bxSlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845180/resetting-bxslider)

```
reloadShow();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call function on a resize event from straight js:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {     ... }
```

Comment: What is the difference? problem is the plugin not resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your code is correct, I added `destroyShow()` before the slider is created...

```
function hSlider(){
    $('.hCarousel').destroyShow().bxSlider({
        displaySlideQty: 3
    });
}

$(window).resize(function(e){
    hSlider();
}).resize();
```

[bxSlider Documentation](http://bxslider.com/options)

Answer (score -1):

I do it the same way but using underscore.js.

```
$(window).resize(_.bind(this.resizeList, this));
```

I think your error is here:

```
$(window).resize(function(e){;  <----- REMOVE THIS ;
    hSlider();
}).resize();                     <----- And I think this is not necessary too
```

Something like this should do it:

```
$(window).resize(function(e){
    hSlider();
});
```

Comment: Bother explaining why the -1 ?